# Regex for alphanumber string

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a alphanumber string that MUST have numbers and MUST have letters in it.

How do I do that?

Comment: So exactly which characters are allowed in an _alphanumber string_? Are spaces allowed? How about newlines or periods? How about Unicode "letters" from another language? Please be more precise and give examples of strings you want to match and examples of strings you do NOT want to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookaheads:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

In order for this match to succeed at least one **ASCII** number and at least on **ASCII** letter must be a part of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind would be a regex like this:

```
(\d.*[a-zA-Z].* | [a-zA-Z].*\d.*)
```

So, a digit, anything, and a letter somewhere, or a letter, anything and a digit somewhere with no beginning or end of string markings.

It's super broad, but does that help at all?